# Create a jquery fixed animation without some overlapping animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this animation http://codepen.io/DWboutin/pen/DFJze

When i go fast over these tabs, the animations makes really weirds things.

How can i stop that? I tried .stop(true,true), i tried to create queue but i can make this cleaner.

This function is triggered when mouseenter

```
var becomeBigger = function(element){
    deplace(element.index(),function(){
        element.dequeue();
        element.queue(function(){
            $(this).animate({top: '118px', height: '435px',width: '248px'},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn,function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
                deplace(element.index());
            });
            $(this).children('.img').children('.noiretblanc').animate({'opacity':0},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn);
            $(this).children('.img').children('.couleur').animate({opacity: 1, top: '-321px'},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn);
            $(this).children('.img').animate({height: '321px'},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn);
            $(this).children('.titre').animate({height: '57px', width: '228px', backgroundColor: '#4696a7'},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn);
            $(this).children('.titre').children('h2').animate({fontSize : '22px'},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn);
            $(this).children('.titre').children('h3').animate({fontSize : '18px'},settings.timeAnimIn,settings.easingIn);
            $(this).children('.btn-verso').css({backgroundPosition : '0 0'});
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });

}
```

And this one on mouseleave

```
var recoverSize = function(element){
    replace(element.index(),function(){
        element.queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).animate({top: '148px',height: '385px',width: '214px'},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.img').children('.noiretblanc').animate({'opacity':1},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.img').children('.couleur').animate({opacity: 0, top: '-277px'},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.img').animate({height: '277px'},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.titre').animate({height: '50px', width: '194px', backgroundColor: '#959595'},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.titre').children('h2').animate({fontSize : '20px'},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.titre').children('h3').animate({fontSize : '16px'},settings.timeAnimOut,settings.easingOut);
            $(this).children('.btn-verso').css({backgroundPosition : '0 -72px'});
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });

}
```

Thank you for all your help

Comment: You need to post your problem code, a link only will get you downvoted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop all animations before you start the current animation, this is easy to do with jQuery:

[stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: I tried it, and it doesnt work. It stop it between states and create weirder effects

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
.stop(false, true).animate(...);
```

or something with clearQueue()

http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: Do i need to put this .stop(false, true) on each .animate() function?

Comment: yes, try it. it stops the running animations and after starts a new one.

Comment: but an other point is: you have so many animate-call in your code. i'm nearly sure that you can do the expected effect with less calls.